# How can I remove a string from every line of a file in the second column of a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

The file structure is like this:

```
34945,/data/file/system01/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/file/system-03stby/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

The result that I am looking for is this:

```
34945,/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

Comment: What rule should be used to remove the string? Should it be some kind of pattern match, or a specific number or directory components?

Comment: Will always be the first 3 directories in the path, i.e /data/file/system01 and the first 2 directories will be the same, the third one will be different

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
$ cat file
34945,/data/file/system01/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/file/system-03stby/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

then

```
$ sed -E 's:,(/[^/]*){3}:,:' file
34945,/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

or similarly

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {sub(/([/][^/]*){3}/,"",$2)} 1' file
34945,/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

In either case, `([/][^/]*){3}` is an extended regular expression matching a slash, followed by zero or more non-slash characters, all 3 times. If the first two directories are constant, you could use something like `sed 's:,/data/file/[^/]*:,:'` or `awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {sub(/data[/]file[/][^/]*[/]/,"",$2)} 1'`.

Or splits and joins in perl:

```
$ perl -F, -lpe '@p = split /\//, $F[1]; $_ = join ",", $F[0], (join "/", @p[4..$#p])' file
34945,data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

Comment: I think you could just use `sed -E 's:(/[^/]*){3}::' file`. Non need for the comma.

Comment: @terdon yeah I really only threw that in to unambiguously anchor it to the start of the second field

Comment: Hmm yes, and that's probably a good idea. The OP did mention the "second column".

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl way, same basic idea as [@steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1395044/85695), but more concise:

```
$ perl -F'[,/]' -nle 'print "$F[0],/",join("/",@F[5..$#F])' file
34945,/data/system/backups/filename.txt
393092,/data/system/backups/filename.extra.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Read `man cut` and use `cut "-d," -f2- | cut -d/ -f5-`  on your file.

Comment: That would result in `data/system/backups/filename.txt` and not `34945,/data/file/system01/data/system/backups/filename.txt` as requested. Also, `,` are not special, there's no need to quote the `"-d,"`.